# Spyder compiler displays wrong output

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

So I am trying to run the following code:

```py
import numpy as np 
import numpy.linalg as la 
x = np.array ( [ [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]] )
y = np.array ( [1, 1, 0, 0] )
# solve using normal equations:
x_transpose = np.transpose(x) #calculating transpose
x_transpose_dot_x = x_transpose.dot(x) # calculating dot product
temp_1 = la.inv(x_transpose_dot_x) #calculating inverse
temp_2 = x_transpose.dot(y)
theta = temp_1.dot(temp_2)
print(theta)
```

The output using spyder IDE:

`[2.22044605e-16 1.11022302e-16 5.00000000e-01]`

The output using collab or py IDE:

`[0.00000000e+00 2.22044605e-16 5.00000000e-01]`

Why is spyder producing a wrong output? I like using spyder tho!

Comment: I’m not sure spyder is producing the wrong answer. I copied you code into Pythonista, ran it and got the same same answer as your Spyder output. Are you using the same python file to run in both Spyder and collab?

Comment: Yes I'm using the same one. I am somehow surprised that each is producing different output. What could be the reason?

Comment: Notice that using `print(np.finfo(float).eps)` you can see that `2.220446049250313e-16` is exactly the machine epsilon. However the `float32` machine epsilon is `print(np.finfo(np.float32).eps) = 1.1920929e-07`. Therefore is you are running 32 bits IDE that may be a reason for the behaviour?